# Add default route in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

When I deploy my MVC3 web site on IIS 7.5 and click on browse (on port 80), my browser display the web site with localhost url (or serverName url) but my default route is like that :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{lang}/{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", lang = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString().Substring(0,2)}
        );

    }
```

Is there an mean in IIS to have full url when I click on browse, i would like to automatically add /fr/Home/Index.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in you web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="Path of your Page" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Comment: </system.webServer> close this at last line,sorry its missed in code

Comment: Thanks, but lang parameters is the computer culture and is dynamically filled

Comment: You can follow this as well

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "",        // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}  // Parameter defaults
        );

Comment: I don't understand :(

Comment: Try this with adding in route config

Comment: How could it work if I remove lang parameter in default route ? and in web.config file , what path must I add ? I would like to prevent user to reach web application with only http://localhost or http://Servername. And when I click on browse in IIS, URL is only http://localhost but I want that url is automatically http://localhost/en/Home/Index or http://localhost/fr/Home/Index, according to OS culture